# What is the proper way to split one source array into a couple of copies?

Tags: arrays, split, rust

Something like this:

```
let source = [0u8; 40];
let a = source[0..11];
let b = source[11..40];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`slice::split_at`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at):

```
fn main() {
    let source = [0u8; 40];
    let (a, b) = source.split_at(11);
    println!("{}, {}", a.len(), b.len())
}
```

There's also [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut), discussed in [How to operate on 2 mutable slices of a Rust array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244762/how-to-operate-on-2-mutable-slices-of-a-rust-array).

In this case, you can also take multiple subslices because it's immutable. These may be overlapping:

```
fn main() {
    let source = [0u8; 40];
    let a = &source[0..11];
    let b = &source[11..40];
    println!("{}, {}", a.len(), b.len())
}
```

> into couple of copies?

The point of slices is that copies **aren't** made. A slice is just a pointer to the start of the data and a length. The data itself is shared.

> I want to make 'a' and 'b' arrays instead of slices

Then you should check out  [How to get a slice as an array in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428920/how-to-get-a-slice-as-an-array-in-rust)

Comment: And if I want to make 'a' and 'b' arrays instead of slices?
"couple of copies" -> means to make a, b independent from source.