# How do I switch two sections of a vector without conflicting borrows?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm going to switch elements in a Vec, but my solution has ownership problem, Is my code totally wrong?

Given `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, the expected output is `[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]`.

```rust
fn switch(nums: &mut Vec<i32>, k: i32) {

    let t = k as usize;
    let v1 = &nums[..t];
    nums.drain(t..);
    nums.extend_from_slice(v1);

}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*nums` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/main.rs:7:5
  |
6 |     let v1 = &nums[..t];
  |               ---- immutable borrow occurs here
7 |     nums.extend_from_slice(v1);
  |     ^^^^^-----------------^^^^
  |     |    |
  |     |    immutable borrow later used by call
  |     mutable borrow occurs here
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.rotate_right

Comment: Very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36244762/1233251 Also, that algorithm would not work as intended even without the intervention of the borrow checker.

Comment: what is the behavior you expect when `k` is not the middle ?

Comment: Thanks all, i am new in Rust and can't understand well in ownership, you guys help me a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either [`rotate_left`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.rotate_left) or [`rotate_right`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.rotate_right), where `mid` is the middle of the vector. This will effectively perform the intended switch.

```
let x = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let mid = x.len() / 2;
```

With `rotate_left`:

```
x.rotate_left(mid);
assert_eq!(&x, &[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]);
```

With `rotate_right`:

```
x.rotate_right(mid);
assert_eq!(&x, &[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]);
```

The same methods are available for plain mutable slices. In the event that the two partitions to swap have the same size but are not contiguous, one can create two iterators of mutable elements and swap them, either using [`swap_with_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap_with_slice)...

```
let (left, right) = x.split_at_mut(mid);
left.swap_with_slice(right);
```

... or by swapping each element one by one.

```
let (left, right) = x.split_at_mut(mid);
for (l, r) in Iterator::zip(left.iter_mut(), right.iter_mut()) {
    std::mem::swap(l, r);
}
assert_eq!(&x, &[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]);
```

See also:

- [How to operate on 2 mutable slices of a Rust array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36244762/1233251)